# How to disable secure boot without entering UEFI?

Tags: linux, laptop, bios, bootloader, secure-boot

My problem is secure boot. I am trying to boot into Linux using a USB but most distros won't work with secure boot, I already know secure boot can be disabled in the UEFI settings, and I know how to get there, but I don't know my UEFI admin password.  So I want a way to disable secure boot without entering UEFI or even better, recover my UEFI admin password. Thanks, I have a Windows 10 64-bit Asus *laptop* .

Comment: The only way to disable Secure Boot is through UEFI.

Comment: All motherboards I've encountered allow adding a Secure Boot entry on the UEFI firmware Boot page _(you'd have to do this for each distro you'd like to boot that doesn't support Secure Boot)_? For the firmware passphrase, the motherboard's OEM's support site should have info on how to clear it, else you'll have to contact them directly - as others have mentioned, it's a firmware accessible option only.

Answer (score 2):

The OS cannot just disable Secure Boot on its own – that would defeat some of the purposes of Secure Boot (e.g. preventing rootkits from installing themselves into the boot chain).

If I remember correctly – Aside from direct user interaction (going through the setup screen), the only other way to control the overall Secure Boot state is by making EFI variable changes that are *signed using the Platform Key (PK).*

But if you're using the "default" Secure Boot setup, then you won't have the private key corresponding to the PK – it exists either only at the manufacturer or nowhere at all. This means going through the firmware setup is your only remaining option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into BIOS (UEFI) to change (disable / enable) Secure Boot.

To do that every time you wish to change OS is a bit onerous.

Somehow you will need to get the password to do this.

I suggest you make your lesser used system a Virtual Machine and your most used system the Host system.

Use VMware Workstation Pro to do this. This has always worked best for me.  I have both VMware and Hyper-V (on a different computer).